# React Native: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just finished a To-Do list tutorial on YouTube for React Native and I decided to try add some features to it such as a confirm modal. Issue is whenever I try pass anything into the modals "Complete Task" onPress I get this error:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Keyboard,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";
import Task from "./components/Task";

export default function App() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState();
  const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);
  const [modalVisable, setModalVisable] = useState(false);
  const [itemToDelete, setItemToDelete] = useState();

  const handleAddTask = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, task]);
    setTask(null);
  };

  const completeTask = (index) => {
    let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
    setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
  };

  const closeModal = (itemToDelete) => {
    completeTask(itemToDelete)
    setModalVisable(false);
  };

  const handleRemoveTask = (index) => {
    setModalVisable(true);
  };

  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.tasksWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Your Tasks</Text>

        <View style={styles.items}>
          {taskItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={index}
                onPress={() => {
                  handleRemoveTask(index);
                  
                }}
              >
                <Task text={item} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </View>

      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
      >
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder={"Add a task!"}
          value={task}
          onChangeText={(text) => setTask(text)}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask()}>
          <View style={styles.addWrapped}>
            <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <View style={styles.modalWrapper}>
        <Modal
          style={styles.modal}
          isVisible={modalVisable}
          onBackdropPress={closeModal}
        >
          <Text style={styles.modalText}>Test Modal</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={closeModal(itemToDelete)}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>
              Complete Task
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#E8EAED",
  },
  tasksWrapper: {
    paddingTop: 80,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  items: {
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  writeTaskWrapper: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 50,
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    borderRadius: 60,
    borderColor: "#C0C0C0",
    borderWidth: 1,
    textAlign: "center",
    width: 300,
  },
  addWrapped: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    borderRadius: 60,
    borderColor: "#C0C0C0",
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  addText: {},
  modalWrapper: {},
  modal: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    maxHeight: 250,
  },
  modalText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  closeButton: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: 30,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#BE33FF",
  },
});
```

I've tried my best to try some work-arounds I could think of but alas, I couldn't find a way. If you have any ideas I'd appriciate your help, thanks Lachie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks suspicious to me

```
onPress={closeModal(itemToDelete)}
```

You are calling the `closeModal` function on **every** render.

The onPress expect a function to call when whatever is pressed.
You should replace it with

```
onPress={function() { closeModal(itemToDelete);}
```

or the shorthand version

```
onPress={() => { closeModal(itemToDelete) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies here:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={closeModal(itemToDelete)}>
```

The `closeModal(itemToDelete)` prop in getting called immediately after rendering, which is itself calling the `completeTask(itemToDelete)`, which is then calling `setTaskItems(itemsCopy)`.
The last function is causing an infinite render cycle.

What you probably want is that the `closeModal(itemToDelete)` be called after the user clicks the `TouchableOpacity` like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={() => closeModal(itemToDelete)}>
```